# Is it possible to make different versions of the same pydantic basemodel?

Tags: python, pydantic

**Explanation of the title:**

Suppose we have the following setup of pydantic models:

```
class ParametersA(BaseModel):
    param_a: str = Field(
        default=...,
        allow_mutation=False,
        exclude=False,
        description="some description.",
        extra={
            "additional_bool": False
        }
    )
    param_b: bool = Field(
        default=False,
        allow_mutation=True,
        exclude=False,
        description="some description.",
        extra={
            "additional_bool": False
        }
    )
    # many more parameters of all types with additional constaints (le, gt, max_items,...)

class ParametersB(BaseModel):
    param_c: float = Field(
        default=-22.0,
        exclude=False,
        allow_mutation=True,
        description="some floaty description",
        gt=-180.0,
        le=0.0,
        extra={
            "additional_bool": False,
            "unit": "degree"
        }
    )
    param_d: List[str] = Field(
        default=["auto"],
        exclude=False, 
        allow_mutation=True,
        min_items=1,
        max_items=4,
        unique_items=True,
        description="Some listy description.",
        extra={
            "auto_mode_available": False
        }
    )
    # many more parameters of all types with additional constaints (le, gt, max_items,...)
```

These two Models are fields in yet another `BaseModel`:

```
class FullModelX(BaseModel):
    parameters_A: ParametersA
    parameters_B: ParametersB
```

The question is if it would be possible to create yet another model:

```
class FullModelY(BaseModel):
    parameters_A: ParametersA
    parameters_B: ParametersB
```

which can reuse the classes `ParametersA` and `ParametersB` but with different validation limits and different meta-data? So for example, in `FullModelX` the default value for `param_b` of `ParametersA` might be `False`, while in `FullModelX` it should be `True`. Same goes for any other  `FieldInfo` property such as `exclude`, `gt`, `le` and so on..

So far my only solution is to duplicate `ParametersA` and `ParametersB` every time I need some other validation constraints.

Comment: Since the validation constraints are *inherent* to the definition of the fields, you aren't really duplicating them, just the unchanged arguments to each call of `Field`. You can define a function like `def param_a(**kwargs): return Field(allow_mutation=True, **kwargs)`, and use that instead of `Field` in a field definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in most cases I think inheritance as suggested by the answer from user @Maxim would be the way to go.

In my particular case pretty much all of the model fields change on or the other `FieldInfo` property, so inheritance would effectively mean rewriting the whole class.

I have found the following solution, which seems to fit my case a bit better. Going by my initial example of changing `param_b` the code for `FullModelY` would look something like this:

```
ParametersAVariant= create_model(
    'ParametersAVariant',
    __base__=ParametersA
    )

ParametersAVariant.__fields__['param_b'].default=True


class FullModelY(BaseModel):
    parameters_A: ParametersAVariant
    parameters_B: ParametersB
```

Not sure if this make the code more readably than simple code duplication, but at least for the most part the initial model can be reused.

Comment: I think this approach is inferior to the straightforward inherit-and-override one because this obscures the actual schema. [_Readability counts._](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020) And one of the strengths of Pydantic models is how clearly everything is laid out in the class definition/namespace. Everything is defined in the same way and in a predictable place. This approach breaks the assumption that I just need to follow the class definitions to see exactly what each schema is. The potential lines of code saved do not justify this obscurity in my option.

Comment: And as a side note: You may as well just inherit instead of dynamically creating the variant model, if all you do is supply a base class. Regardless of what you later do with its `__fields__` attribute.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg I agree, those are some good arguments.